# How to get the invoking node in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events

Given `function act()` in the JavaScript and `<p id="one" onclick="act()">`, `<p id="two" onclick="act()">`, can I get to know the `p`, which has been pressed *without* using `onclick="act(this)"`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it *is* possible:

```
<button onclick="called()" id="one">click</button>
<script>
function called()
{
    console.log(window.event);
}
</script>
```

Trawl around inside `window.event` to find the targeted element, event type, and other info

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

You need to pass `this` (or `event`, which contains source information).
If you want to, you can write `act.call(this)`, which will call the function in the context of the element, so that `this` inside `act` will refer to the element.

Although some browsers also expose the event object as a global, not all browsers do this, so you cannot rely on this behavior.

Comment: @Andrey: Not without passing _some_ parameter.

Comment: the default paramater is the event object which has access to the <p> object

Comment: I beg to differ, see my answer. Also another alternative would be to pass the id to act

Comment: @Isaac: Not in Firefox.  Also, I dislike relying on globals like that.

Comment: @SLaks regardless, it answers the question. I really hope Fluffy never actually uses the `window.event` method though